# APACHE: Cipher for TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA is not working

Tags: apache, ssl, weak

I have the following line in my `httpd.conf`:

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!DES-CBC3-SHA:!ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
```

If I check my webserver on ssllabs.com, I see that:

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa)   WEAK   128
```

Anybody here who can help me with that? As far as I understood, this is already incl. Into the `SSLCipherSuite` Line. Thanks!

Comment: You say it's not working, yet ssllabs shows it!? What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: And what do you mean by "not working"?